# Restriction Estimate with curved surfaces

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Consider the restriction estimate:
$$
\left\|\hat f \right\|_{L^q(S)}\leq C(p,q,S)\left\| f\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)},
$$
where $S$ is a compact $n-1$ smooth surface with nonvanishing Gaussian curvature.

I am wondering if the above estimate holds if and only if it just holds for the sphere $\mathbb S^{n-1}$. I was thinking if the parabolic rescaling in Guth's 2016 Paper :

https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1916

would prove it, but I cannot find any reference for that.

My idea: for simplicity, consider $n=1$. We can define a natural bijection from an arc of the circle (say, the lower 1/4 quadrant that resembles $f(x)=x^2-1$ on $|x|\leq 1/2$).